# Creating dictionary from list in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a very large python list of strings , and I want to create a dictionary with word as a key and its frequency as a value. what is the efficient way of doing this.
Here is the my solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def make_dictionary(list_of_words):
    file_dict=defaultdict(int)
    for w in list_of_words:
        file_dict[w]+=1
    return file_dict
```

As i have a list of very large size and i don't want to iterate over the list.what is the better option for me to reduce the time complexity ?

Comment: Simply use a `Counter`. It is a special dictionary and works on average in *O(n)* (worst case *O(n^2)*).

Comment: Is there any option to reduce complexity less than O(n) ?

Comment: Of course not, how can one read *n* words without reading all *n* of them?

Comment: I have thousands of files and each fie has thousands of words , then how can i reduce the how can i reduce time complexity ? my algorithm is giving very bad performance .

Answer (score 2):

That's the job of `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
dictionary = Counter(list_of_words)
```